# How to add radius to current location and get a new lat long?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Hello everyone,
              i got current lat long with the using of CoreLocation framework, now i want to add 1 km to current location/current lat long and need to new lat long.so is there any method ?

Thank you in advance

hello every one as suggested by @SKT, that link solve my problem.
here is link
[Get locations within a radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548857/get-locations-within-a-radius)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548857/get-locations-within-a-radius

Comment: Please refer this below link which may help you -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance

Comment: @SKT i dont have targetLocation.

Comment: @SKT :: Thank you bro...ur suggestion is acceptable...

Comment: @BandishDave then make it useful by marking add something useful tag